# Why couldn't I use the functions in the included header file by including header files it includes

Tags: c++, include, header-files

There is a header file called `ose.h`, this header file contains some code like this:

```
#include <osetypes.h>
#include <osarch.h>
#include <itc.h>
......  
LITS_WRAP_FUNC(union SIGNAL*, alloc, OSBUFSIZE size, SIGSELECT signo)
{ return zzalloc(size, signo); }
```

In my `.cc` file, if I include the `ose.h`, I'm able to call the function `zzalloc` directly, but if I include **all** the header files `ose.h` includes, I couldn't call the `zzalloc` function, why? I don't know where is the `zzalloc` function come from, probably from some `.so` and `.a` files, but I can't see it. How can I call the functions directly like `ose.h` without including `ose.h` in my code?

Comment: Why you don't want to use ose.h?

Comment: LITS_WRAP_FUNC could be a macro defined in ose.h. zzalloc could be defined in ose.h. Note also that it could be an `extern "C"`.

Comment: @chmike yes, it is a `extern "C"`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ you only know making duplication.

Comment: So to be able to call zzaloc, you must declare it as exterrn "C" in a header file and include the header file. Define in a similar way all functions you might want to use.